# Decode error while loading json file to python

Tags: python, json

This is my json file:

```
{
    "43455": ["(\(.*\))"],
    "55655": ["(\d{2,3})\"]
}
```

When I try loading it to my python script I get an error:

```
with open('link_to_file', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    field_regex = json.loads(file.read())
```

> JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape

Tried changing encoding but still no luck... any ideas..?

Comment: Just because you put something that *looks* like JSON in a file that ends with ``.json`` does not make it **valid** JSON. You could use a validator like https://jsonlint.com/ to check if your JSON is actually valid.

Comment: What did you expect to be the result?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did expect it to load properly so I could use the regex code depending on the id. The answer by Wura helped

Comment: The question is, did you expect the regex pattern to be `(\d{2,3})\ ` or `(\d{2,3})`? The trailing `\ ` seems suspicious.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thanks for noticing. I actually have a field with numerical strings like this one:
`13" (50lg) 40!` and I wanted to extract the double or triple digit number in front of double quote sign. So for that to work I guess I need to add another double qoute sign in my json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape backslashs

```
{
    "43455": ["(\\(.*\\))"],
    "55655": ["(\\d{2,3})\\"]
}
```